# How can I create indexes in marklogic after loading documents programatically

Tags: indexing, marklogic

Please help me with that:

How can I create indexes in marklogic after loading documents programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just did. No further action is needed unless you want to change the default indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about adding or changing index settings from the defaults, you can use the [Admin API](http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/admin.xml&category=Admin%20Library).

Answer (score 0):

Using Admin API you can create index. First in the left tab of your admin page click on

`Databases->your database name->click on type of indexes(element,attribute,field,path)`.

Then in right tab click on **Add** tab & specify your index details.